# Would my class written below be considered as correct code

Tags: python, function, class

My question is not related to an issue or problem I am encountering.. My question refers to 'good practices' and even more : practice that makes sense. I've written many scripts in different languages and I am familair with PEP-8 coding standards, so I am not asking you guys to look at my code from that perspective, rather from a practical point of view, being: would the below make sense, or would a simple function(with some, some, **kwargs) also be considered good in this example? I am figuring out if I should consider working more with classes.

Thanks for taking the time to read my post. Best to all!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import re
import time

def reset_values_to_default():

    dict_of_values = {
        'FilePath' : 'C:/PythonProjects/Compare/output/ Report from 23-02-2020.xlsx',
        'Planned in period' : 0,
        'Backlog from last month' : 0,
        'Current planned date' : pd.to_datetime('01-01-' + pd.Timestamp.now().strftime('%Y')).date(),
        'Current month' : pd.Timestamp.now().month,
        'Days in current month' : pd.Timestamp.now().days_in_month,
        'Routing' : 1,
        'Feasible' : False,
        'Organization Name' : 'test_organization'
        }

    return dict_of_values

class planning:

    def __init__(self, parameters):
        name = 'create planning for: '

        self.parameters = parameters
        self.file_path = parameters['FilePath']
        self.routing = parameters['Routing']
        self.org_name = parameters['Organization Name']

        planning.get_main_data(self)

        if self.routing == 1:
            planning.standard_planning_route(self)
        elif self.routing == 2:
            planning.custom_planning(self)


        print(name, self.org_name)

    def standard_planning_route(self):
        print('activating variant 1')
        df = self.frame['ID']

    def custom_planning(self):
        print('activating variant 2')
        df = self.frame['ID']
        return df

    def get_main_data(self):
        if not os.path.exists(self.file_path):
            print('no input file found, quitting function')
            exit()
        else:
            self.frame = pd.read_excel(self.file_path, sheet_name='Master')
            #return self.frame


x = planning( reset_values_to_default() ).custom_planning()

print(x)
```

Comment: This might be better suited for the code review site: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - my initial comment is that I'd try to avoid sending in a dictionary as parameters - you can use named parameters instead (and unpack the arguments with `**`), and then, as you suggest, handle any unknown parameters if necessary (if you expect and want to handle those, if not - don't support them) with `kwargs`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use sys.exit, especially if your code is going to be deployed to a production environment. In addition, I would recommend to use a logger instead of print statements [logger](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html). Moreover, the first letter of the class name should be in capital.

Also you could add some comments like below (instead of adding them above the function):

```
def get_main_data(self):
    '''
    Some comments here
    '''
    if not os.path.exists(self.file_path):
        print('no input file found, quitting function')
        exit()
    else:
        self.frame = pd.read_excel(self.file_path, sheet_name='Master')
        #return self.frame
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Will definitely implement sys.exit and change first letter to capital. What is the reason it is important to name a class with Capital?

Comment: Happy to help @ko_00. Regarding the capital, it is a PEP 8 naming convention --> https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things.

In `reset_values_to_default()`, you could save `pd.Timestamp.now()` as a variable, then use it in the dict. This is an edge case, but it prevents you getting the subsequent calls to `pd.Timestamp.now()` from overlapping two different months.

---

Classes should have the first letter capitalised.

```
class Planning:
    pass
```

---

As @MatsLindh mentioned, `kwargs` would be better than a dict here. Or just have only parameters you need in the constructor as you're going to get a `KeyError` anyway if you don't provide them.

```
def __init__(self, file_path, routing, org_name):
    self.file_path = file_path
    self.routing = routing
    self.org_name = org_name
```

or with `kwargs`

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.file_path = kwargs['file_path']
    self.routing = kwargs['routing']
    self.org_name = kwargs['org_name']

# Planning(file_path='/path', routing='routes', org_name='stackoverflow')
```

---

You're setting instance variables for the first time outside of the `__init__` method. This is not recommended. And it doesn't look like you need to store `self.routing` or `self.file_path` anyway. You could do this:

```
def __init__(self, file_path, routing, org_name):
    self.org_name = org_name

    if not os.path.exists(file_path):
        print('No input file found. Exiting...')
        raise FileNotFoundError()
    self.frame = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name='Master')
    print(f'Activating variant {routing}')
    self.df = self.frame['ID']

planning = Planning(reset_values_to_default())
print(planning.df)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. You are indeed correct that some parameters will not change.